# Is there a way of changing the size of an image after a loading screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know how to change the size of an image, however, I have a loading screen set up and I have the text and the image set up with a  so after showPage, 1500 the text and image appear however when I try to change the size of the image it won't change

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 1500);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "flex";
}
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
 }
 img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

```css
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


/* Add animation to "page content" */

.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from {
    bottom: -100px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatebottom {
  from {
    bottom: -100px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

#myDiv {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<HTML lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="dropdownmenu.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="rainbowheading.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="loadingcss.css">
  <script src="loading.js"></script>
  <title> North Macedonia </title>

</head>
       <div class="container">
    <h1 class="rainbow"> The pearl of the Balkans: Macedonia </h1>
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">Macedonian Dispora</a>
      <a href="cities.html">Cities</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">History
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Ancient History</a>
          <a href="#">Ottoman Period</a>
          <a href="#">Yugoslav Period</a>
          <a href="#">Modern History</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">

  <div id="loader"></div>

  <div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
    <div>
      <h2>x</h2>
      <p>x</p>
    </div>
    <img id="image1" src="./images/ohridindex.jpg" alt="image" />
  </div>
```

I tried setting dimensions and etc. however the image remains static, any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Where are you setting image dimensions in the above code?

Comment: I was trying 600x1200

Comment: Add whatever code you were trying in the question

Comment: Why have you a `div` in the `head` tag? This is definitely not the right place. Did you mean a `header` tag? Checkout what a valid html layout is https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp

Comment: I fixed the <div>

Comment: I added the one i tried but for some reason, it completely ignores the request to change the size for some reason something is blocking it